# Unable to get response from HttpURLConeection

Tags: android, rest

I am new to android. I want to call an API from my localhost but I am not receiving any response. Here is my code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopify_list);

InputStream inputStream = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
URL url = null;

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopify_list);

InputStream inputStream = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
URL url = null;

try {

    url = new URL("http://localhost/practice/json.php");

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){
        response.append(line);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e){

} finally {

    if( inputStream != null ){

        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored){

        }
    }
    if( urlConnection != null ){
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I am not able to see the Toast on screen. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try printing response in log .also check UI thread and background thread in Android.

Comment: is your server running?

Comment: Actually, there was an issue with the permission of the internet to the application but now I am facing another issue and that is bufferedReader.readLine() returning response but while not executing and response.toString() returning empty response.